# Nested mocked method is not getting called in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

let's assume I have this simple scenario.

```
package kivoxdaemon.utils;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public class TempTest {

   @Test
   public void test() {

      TestMock testMock = Mockito.mock(TestMock.class);

      Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(testMock).method1();

      Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
         @Override
         public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Mock method3");
            return null;
         }
      }).when(testMock).method3();

      testMock.method1();
   }

}

class TestMock {

   void method1() {
      System.out.println("method1");
      method2();
   }

   private void method2() {
      System.out.println("method2");
      method3();
   }

   void method3() {
      System.out.println("method3");
   }
}
```

This code has the following output in console:

method1

method2

method3

whereas I would expect it to be 

method1

method2

Mock method3

Method 3 is mocked, so why isn't it getting called?

Can you please suggest how to implement such I believe very common scenario, when the call chain starts from a real public method, but some other methods, called internally, have to be mocked?

Thank you in advance.

UPD: Just figured out that was because of mock-maker-inline property applied via org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker file.

Comment: I don't think it's a common scenario at all (at least I've never seen it).  Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: Your actual code seems ok. Are you sure that you run really the code what you posted here ?

Comment: @davidxxx Yes, absolutely sure. I am using Mockito v 2.12

Comment: I just tested with Mockito 1.9.5, it works. Maybe something differs in Mockito 2.12. I will try.

Comment: @JoeC Say, you have a class, you want to test, and this class has a (number of) getter(s) returning objects, created in the constructor, that you cannot instantiate in testing infrastructure, like DB / network access, and instead you want those getters to return some stubs.

Comment: I have some runtime exception because of missing classes but sorry not time to analyse that now.

Comment: I tried it with mockito 1.9.5, 1.10.19 and 2.12.0 (basically just copied&pasted your code) - works fine with all three of them, result is the same: "Mock method3 ".

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Just updated: the strange behaviour was caused by mock-maker-inline property.

Comment: If so, consider to A) write a real self-answer, that shows the problem and its solution B) to delete the question. This is a QA site - content here should be helpful for future readers, and given the current content ... I dont see that.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please suggest how to implement such I believe very common scenario

As @JoeC wrote, this is *not* a common scenario.

The reason is: you test the behavior of *Mockito*, but you should test *your codes* behavior instead.

In order to do so you instantiate your *code under test* without mocking it and pass in mocks for its *dependencies*.

Comment: Technically, one could argue that method3 is actually just a hidden dependency, so it might be a good idea to think about refactoring it into an explicit one.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz: *"one could argue that method3 is actually just a hidden dependency"* I think your assumption is based on the OP wish to mock that method call but as far as I see this is just wild guessing. Maybe she is doing UnitTesting the wrong way by testing implementation details. But yes: if method 3 hides the access to a dependency it should be refactored.